# Flash builder installing failed on android device

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I made the simple application using flash builder 4.5.1 for both iOS and android. I test the application on my iphone and ipad, it working fine. But when I try to install on my android device(Samsung GT-5570). It get the following error message.

```
Error occurred while installing the application:
1603 KB/s (6108444 bytes in 3.719s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Runtime.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

I google about the error.I found that It is cause of my device have ARMv6 architecture. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/890214

Now I have 2 question.
Question 1. Is there any other reason of failing installation.
Question 2. If the reason is same than any other way available to make build for ARMv6 and ARMv7 architecture phone.

One more thing my both iOS devices are of ARMv7 architecture.

Thanks
MD

Comment: Not meeting system reqs is usually enough. Does it have AIR installed as well?

Comment: Air is not installed on device.. Means now user needs to install air before install application?

Comment: With Android, that's the way it works - when your flex mobile app packages for iOS, it uses "Captive Runtime", packaging binaries that run the app as a stand-alone. With Android, this functionality will be  introduced in AIR 3 with FB 4.6. 
So try installing AIR on your Android phone first - but your phone might not meet system reqs for it.

Comment: SQLiteNoob you means I cann't run application on my android device.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to run your AIR apps on your device.

Check out specs (system requirements) for AIR here:

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html

Adobe also has a list of Certified Devices:

http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/